# How to make two lines on either side of the navigation bar?

Tags: html, css, navbar

I would like the navbar to look like this, with two horizontal lines on either side of the navbar.
[image]
html code:

```html
    <div id="navbar">
    <div id="navbar-links">
    <a class="active" href="#home">HOME</a>
    <a href="#about">ABOUT</a>
    <a href="#works">WORKS</a>
    <a href="#contact">CONTACT</a>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Please show us the relevant CSS - for instance how is that navbar being centered?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you want exactly but I tried to follow the image with the html you provided. This method uses two spans, one before and one after the links. You can adjust the font sized and sizes/colours of the lines as you please.

This will appear differently if you are using Bootstrap.

```css
.left, .right{
  flex-grow: 1;
  background: linear-gradient(lightskyblue, lightskyblue);
  background-position: 0% 50%;
  background-size: 100% 2px;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
}


#navbar-links>a{
  color:black;
  float: left;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 25%; 
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
    <div id="navbar" style="width:95%;display: flex;margin: 40px auto;">
        <span class='left'></span> 
      <div id="navbar-links" style="width:65%; padding: 0 5px">
      <a class="active" href="#home">HOME</a>
      <a href="#about">ABOUT</a>
      <a href="#works">WORKS</a>
      <a href="#contact">CONTACT</a>
      </div>
          <span class='right'></span>
      </div>
    </h3>
```

Comment: thank you. It worked.  I have to try this with my css

Answer (score 0):

Depending on exactly what the surrounding CSS is, but given just the HTML in the question, you could put a line as background to the whole navbar using a linear-gradient and blank it out under the actual links by giving that a white background.

```css
#navbar {
  background-image: linear-gradient(transparent 0 49%, blue 49% 51%, transparent 51% 100%);
  position: relative;
  rdisplay: inline-block;
  margin: 0 1vw;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

#navbar-links {
  background: white;
  padding: 0 2vw;
}

#navbar-links a{
  color: gray;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="navbar">
  <div id="navbar-links">
    <a class="active" href="#home">HOME</a>
    <a href="#about">ABOUT</a>
    <a href="#works">WORKS</a>
    <a href="#contact">CONTACT</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

You will need to play around with the padding or margins to get the spacing that you want.

Comment: how add more padding only for horizontal line?

Comment: Do you want the blue lines to look shorter? And on both sides or just the middle part or the far left and right edges? Try changing the padding of navbar-links to get more padding either side of links.

Comment: yes. I want 2 short lines.

Comment: with more thickness

Comment: Thickness is controlled by the %s in the linear-gradient. Give the blue part more of the %, say 47% 53%